# Exchanging AES Key and VI between C# and PHP using RSA doesn't work (Encoding)

Tags: c#, php, aes, rsa, phpseclib

I try to exchange an AES key between C# and PHP using HTTPWebRequest:

```
// This is to send the request to php using UTF8
public string SendRequest(Uri path, NameValueCollection nvc)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);

    byte[] input = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GetPostString(nvc));

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = input.Length;

    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();

    return result;
}
// That's a piece of code of how i try to send the C#'s public key to php:

     string result = SendRequest(builder.Uri, publicKeyNVC);

     string[] parts = Regex.Split(result, "</seperator>");

     this.cryptoHelper.ExchangedAESKey = this.cryptoHelper.DecryptRSA(parts[0]);
     this.cryptoHelper.ExchangedAESIV = this.cryptoHelper.DecryptRSA(parts[1]);
```

And here is the important part of my exchange-php-file:

```
$key = md5(uniqid());

$size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$public = str_replace('</RSAKeyValue>', '<P></P><Q></Q><DP></DP><DQ></DQ><InverseQ></InverseQ><D></D></RSAKeyValue>', $public_key);

$rsa->loadKey($public, CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_XML);
$rsa->loadKey($rsa->getPublicKey());

$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);

$ciphertext_key = ($rsa->encrypt($key));
$ciphertext_iv = ($rsa->encrypt($iv));
echo ($ciphertext_key."</seperator>".$ciphertext_iv);

echo "</seperator>".$key."|".strlen($ciphertext_key)."|".strlen($ciphertext_iv);
```

Sorry for posting so much code, but I can't be sure where my misstake is hidden. My problem is, that the length requested by php of

```
echo "</seperator>".$key."|".strlen($ciphertext_key)."|".strlen($ciphertext_iv);
```

(128) isn't the same length like the response I receive. The response in DecryptRSA(parts[0]) has, decoded with UTF8, more then 200 bytes, so the RSADecrypt-Method, of course, gets an error.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the ciphertext created by PHP is binary, and as a result of interpreting the web response as UTF-8 in C# it is being corrupted. You cannot treat arbitrary binary data as strings, they must be processed as binary or converted to an appropriate textual form e.g. Base64. You could try replacing this:

```
echo ($ciphertext_key."</seperator>".$ciphertext_iv);
```

with:

```
echo (base64_encode($ciphertext_key)."</seperator>".base64_encode($ciphertext_iv));
```

Then on the C# side replace:

```
 this.cryptoHelper.ExchangedAESKey = this.cryptoHelper.DecryptRSA(parts[0]);
 this.cryptoHelper.ExchangedAESIV = this.cryptoHelper.DecryptRSA(parts[1]);
```

with:

```
 this.cryptoHelper.ExchangedAESKey = this.cryptoHelper.DecryptRSA(Convert.FromBase64String(parts[0]));
 this.cryptoHelper.ExchangedAESIV = this.cryptoHelper.DecryptRSA(Convert.FromBase64String(parts[1]));
```

(You will presumably need to change the signature of `DecryptRSA()` to accept a `byte[]` and remove whatever `string` to `byte[]` conversion is going on within that method currently).

Finally, is there any reason you're not just using SSL? It's going to be far more secure than this scheme (since you have no protection against man-in-the-middle attacks here for example.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response ;) Converting to base-64 and reading the data as ISO-8859-1, because the webserver also encodes the response (instead of UTF-8), worked. I just wanted to implement a way you can use my project I'm working on right now without having SSL serverside, because not everyone has the opportunity to use it. Of course, SSL will be used primarily.